# Serverless Custom Authorizer results to undefined

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I followed the tutorials and examples online on how to implement custom authorizers for my lambda function. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble accessing the authorizer context inside my function. Doing `console.log(event.requestContext.authorizer);` only results to `undefined`. Am I missing something? Here's some snippet.

```
# serverless.yml

...
myAuthorizer:
  handler: src/functions/myAuthorizer/index.handler

someFunction:
  handler: src/functions/someFunction/index.handler
  events:
    - http:
        method: GET
        path: /hello-world
        authorizer:
          name: myAuthorizer
          identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
```

```js
// myAuthorizer.ts

export async function handler(
  event: AWSLambda.CustomAuthorizerEvent,
  context: AWSLambda.Context
): Promise<AWSLambda.AuthResponse> {

  const user = {id: 1, email: 'user@test.com'};

  // some logic...

  return {
    principalId: user.id,
    policyDocument: {
      Version: '2012-10-17',
      Statement: [
        {
          Action: '*',
          Effect: 'Allow',
          Resource: '*',
        },
      ],
    },
    context: { user },
  };
}
```

```js
// someFunction.ts

export async function handler(
  event: AWSLambda.APIGatewayEvent,
  context: AWSLambda.Context
): Promise<AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyResult> {

  console.log(event.requestContext.authorizer); // <-- this is undefined
  console.log(Object.keys(event.requestContext)); // <-- no "authorizer" property
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world'}),
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `myAuthorizer` handler function, use `callback` style instead of using `async/await` style.

```
export async function handler(
  event: AWSLambda.CustomAuthorizerEvent,
  context: AWSLambda.Context
): Promise<void> { // change to void

  const user = { id: 1, email: 'user@test.com' };

  // some logic...

  context.succeed({ // instead of return policy object
    principalId: user.id,
    policyDocument: {
      Version: '2012-10-17',
      Statement: [
        {
          Action: '*',
          Effect: 'Allow',
          Resource: '*',
        },
      ],
    },
    context: { user },
  });
}
```

Comment: but do you have any idea why callback works and not `async/await`? In any case, they should explicitly mention that somewhere in their documentation. :(

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know :( , I faced the same issue and there is the way I do. Maybe `async/await` will working fine on `Lambda` environment, but not for local env, `callback` stype woking for both envs.

Comment: Yeah. they owe us explanation though. :) thanks again!

Comment: Wow AWS really is a big can of undocumented bugs isn't it lol. No wonder people get paid so much for being experts in it - they need to memorise all these obscure issues

Comment: This answer deserves better. I saw tons of answers using `event.requestContext` or `context.identity` but none of them were talking about cases where these values don't exist.